# Combination of HTTP Filter not working with ignore() method from WebSecurity

Tags: spring, spring-security, filter, http-status-code-404, spring-filter

I have made `Filter` which is added like that in `Spring Security`:

```
   @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/#/", "resources/static/**").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth").permitAll().anyRequest().permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // We filter the api/login requests
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/api/auth", authenticationManager()),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Unfortunately request `/api/auth` has no `controller` in my `Spring Boot` app. It only works in `filter`. So the frontend hit this api to authenticate yourself.

In my app I also had to add

```
  @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/static/**").anyRequest();
    }
```

to ignore `static` files because the first method doesn't exclude it properly. And the `ignore()` cause the problem because it calls `/api/auth` which has no equivalent in backend but only exists in `.js` files. What is more `ignore()` method ignore all requests from the path in which `/api/auth` is - this api returns `404` when I want to call when `ignore()` method is uncommented. So the question is how to make a work around to make it work properly?

Comment: You question is very confusing. What does *It only works in filter. So the frontend hit this api to authenticate yourself.* mean? If you permit `/api/auth`, you should reach your servlet filter without a problem.

Comment: Yes but only this api/Auth doesn’t work

Comment: And what you mean by *And the ignore() cause the problem because it calls /api/auth*? `ignore`is not calling anything at all.

Comment: What does *Yes but only this api/Auth doesn’t work* mean? What is not working? What is the result?

Comment: Exactly it doesn’t call anything. But (what I understand- maybe it is wrong) the case the api/Auth doesn’t have equivalent in backend beyond that filter. So with that ignore() method browser throw 404 error. But with this it works fine (only when I run in dev mode -like localhost:4200) but when I copy all frontend files to static directory and run as localhost8091 - Spring Boot app, it throws errors

Comment: If you have no controller or filter behind `/api/auth`you should always get 404, with or without ignoring `/api/auth`. But you wrote, that you have a servlet filter, that handles `/api/auth`, so you should never get 404. Could you show the configuration of the servlet filter? Is the URL mapping right? Or did you apply the filter for all URLs?

Comment: I'm not sure, but you can try. But I see, that you added the servlet filter to Spring Security's filter chain. That means, if you ignore the configuration for the URL (you didn't do it in your question, but your comments are not so clear), the whole configuration with your filter is not executed. So yes, if your configure `ignoring().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/auth")` your filter is not applied. In that case you get 404.